# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler", but gem list does not have the version that it says is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I'm using rbenv, ruby 2.6.5, and attempting to use bundler 2.0.2. Currently when I run `gem list`, bundler 2.0.2 is the only version shown on the screen. However, when I run `bundle install` in my project, an error is thrown stating that my current bundler version is `2.1.2`. If I run bundler version in the shell, it indeed says 2.1.2. Where can I find this version and eliminate it?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: `which bundle` and `gem which bundle` May be enlightening

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all versions of bundler with `gem uninstall bundler` and install the version you need again.